# How to use Highcharts Drupal 7 module

Tags: drupal, highcharts, view

How to use Highcharts Drupal 7 module. I tried using views integration but not settings are available. But i saw an image http://drupal.org/files/views_settings.png like this. In my drupal instalation when i click on settings for Highchart these options are not there. Can anybody help me please.

Answer (score 5):

This two tutorials may help you.. just follow the exact instructions

http://webwash.net/tutorials/intro-visualization-api-part-1-views-and-gva
http://webwash.net/tutorials/intro-visualization-api-part-2-highcharts-and-code