# Drupal Visualization without Aggregation in Views

Tags: drupal, highcharts, view, visualization, aggregation

I am trying to create a chart from really simple data.  I am using the highcharts library and the drupal visualization module and views.  It seems like the only type of graphs that I see examples of on the Internet involve aggregation.  For example, someone wants to find the number of taxonomy terms used in the nodes of a particular content type and they use a pie chart to show the percentage (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ot2cFQVgzfA&spfreload=1).

The type of data I am trying to visualize is something like this.

```
      Year   Products
    +------+----------+
    | 2015 +    78    +
    +------+----------+
    | 2014 +    74    +
    +------+----------+
    | 2013 +   123    +
    +------+----------+
    | 2012 +   106    +
    +------+----------+
    | 2011 +    59    +
    +------+----------+ 
    |  ... +    ...   +
```

I want my x-axis to be Year and my y-axis to be Sales.  My content type has each of these fields.  In views I am only including the years field and the sales field, which are both integers.

If I view the data as an HTML Grid I see this at the bottom of the views page:

```
Title
Test

Content
2015
78

2014
74

2013
123

2012
106

2011
59
```

So it looks like view is showing both fields.  But when I use Visualization (Highcharts) - Line Chart instead of HTML Grid I get:

[Test Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGEBX.png)

The query produced by views is:

```
SELECT TOP(10) node.[nid] AS [nid], node.[created] AS [node_created], 'node' AS field_data_field_year_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_products_node_entity_type
FROM 
{node} node
WHERE ( (( ([node].[status] = '1') AND ([node].[type] IN  ('year')) )) )
ORDER BY node_created DESC
```

This makes me think views cannot do a JOIN to get the results from both the node and the product field tables.  Instead it is using node as a text value, not an integer, so the chart shows values of zero.  Interestingly in views the HTML Chart format can get the values, just not the Visualization format.

How can I create a simple chart based on two columns of data using Highcharts and Visualization?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15702462/4046096) from an [another SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700276/how-to-use-highcharts-drupal-7-module) will be helpful for you. Alternatively you could use [Highcharts Cloud](http://www.highcharts.com/cloud/how-to-share-on-blogs-webpages/embed-in-drupal) or Drupal plugin - [Easychart](http://www.easychart.org/) - visual editor for Highcharts.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by doing the following in my view:

-- Format > Visualisation > Settings:

> --- Field Settings: enable only the field that you want to use in the
>   y-axis.
>   --- X-axis settings: choose the field you want to use on the x-axis.

-- Fields > [your y-axis field]:

> ---- Rewrite results to strip HTML tags from this field